# can one tmux pane be aware of what's being typed in another tmux pane?

Tags: command-line-interface, tmux

I use tmux daily mostly for the pane/window features it provides, I also like being able to attach/detach from sessions and have sessions scripting using tmuxinator.  I know there's a lot more that can be done with tmux than I currently know... for example I've seen tmux send-keys (but never used them, though it looks awesome)...

So my question... can one tmux pane be aware of what's being typed in another tmux pane?  And further, could a program running in a pane (not just tmux itself) be aware or made aware of what's being typed in another pane?

Can I be doing work in one pane and have a separate pane that's programmitically set to respond to it in certain ways... like when primary pane runs command x the secondary pane runs command y?

What kind of tmux magic sauce can I put on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `tmux pipe-pane`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing `tmux pipe-pane`.  From first research it appears to literally send "output" of commands in current pane to a command running in the specified pane.  So.... 1) does that mean that the specified/target/destination pane cannot necessarily respond to the command that was typed as it only received the *output* from the typed command?  2) What about something like a REPL that I don't think actually has any output... would the destination/target pane be unable to evaluate what's typed into a REPL in the source/origin pane?

Comment: The issue here is that tmux doesn't know about what is and isn't command To solve this, you gotta look at a different layer in the stack. Maybe look at your bash manual for example.

Comment: Are there any common use cases for `pipe-pane`?  The only example of its use I've seen are simply doing `tmux pipe-pane -t 0.2 'cat >> ~/tmux_pipe-pane.log'`.  Is logging the main purpose of this command?  Or maybe there's an infinitely wide array of possibility for it?

Comment: I'd say there are as many uses for it as there are uses for, well, pipes. Any pipeline like `c1 | c2` you might have used, you can replace `c1` with whatever command is running in a `tmux` pane.